# Blooming Problems 6

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I can survive in Antarctica if I am of hardier type

My ways with flowers are various from what we give for hype

We can be eaten by some animals, including the lemurs of Madagascar

But we are well known for being in an East so far

Name the plant

Comment: Are the lemurs mainly Rot13(evat-gnvyrq)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this

> Bamboo?

I can survive in Antarctica if I am of hardier type

> Some species of bamboo can survive [in -20 degrees Celsius temperatures](https://www.bigbamboo.rs/en/blog/where-does-bamboo-grow/).

My ways with flowers are various from what we give for hype

> Bamboo doesn’t flower very often, and in fact it’s the stalks of the bamboo that are used more often by humans for making things.

We can be eaten by some animals, including the lemurs of Madagascar

> Bamboo can be poisonous; the shoots contain [cyanide](https://poisonousplants.ansci.cornell.edu/adapt/lemur.html) although Madagascar Bamboo Lemurs are able to eat it (pandas do too, more famously).

But we are well known for being in an East so far

> Bamboo is a “traditionally Chinese plant” and is often associated with China (although it grows on 5 of 7 continents naturally).

Answer (score 1):

Is it maybe:

> Agave?

I can survive in Antarctica if I am of hardier type

> There are some species of agave that are quite cold-hardy. Example: Agave parryi ssp parryi can survive temperatures as low as -29°C.

My ways with flowers are various from what we give for hype

> Their flowers are not really what we would conventionally call beautiful flowers.

We can be eaten by some animals, including the lemurs of Madagascar

> Agave's flowers are edible and I know lemurs do eat them.

But we are well known for being in an East so far

> I am not really sure what this means.. Is "being in an East so far" referred to the plant being in a hot climate? Because if so, then this is covered too.

Also,

> I just found out that there is a neighborhood of modern architecture homes located in east Austin, called Agave. So maybe that explains the last part?

Comment: No, sorry though

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a

> **Wort**?

`I can survive in Antarctica if I am of hardier type`

> [Pearl**wort**](https://theantarcticpearlwort.weebly.com/).

`My ways with flowers are various from what we give for hype`

> There are [heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wort_plants)!

`We can be eaten by some animals, including the lemurs of Madagascar`

> [St. John's **Wort**](http://www.invasives.org.za/legislation/item/263-st-john-s-wort-hypericum-perforatum) found in South Africa (although [this site](https://www.invasivespeciesinfo.gov/plants/stjohnswort.shtml) does not agree, so let's just say Africa), home to [Ring-Tailed **Lemurs**](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/mammals/r/ring-tailed-lemur/) in **Madagascar**.

`But we are well known for being in an East so far`

> That very wort can be found in Eastern Canada ("**an East**" $\to$ **East**ern C**an**ada).

Comment: No, this is incorrect

Comment: @XavierStanton ah dang. I was feeling confident with this answer, especially since Rot13(n crney vf n uneq zngrevny). Oh well. Nice riddle, though :D